# Why in the same query, hash index is ignored and btree index is used

Tags: postgresql

I think both cases only need to scan the indexes, but this is not the case. Only BTree index is used.

The following is an example

```sql
drop table if exists test;

create table test
(
    id    serial4 primary key,
    name  varchar(255) not null,
    score int          not null
);
```

I inserted 1,000,000 rows. 9867 rows score is 0.

Explain With Hash Indexes

```sql
drop index if exists test_score_zero;
create index test_score_zero on test using hash (id) where score = 0;
explain select id from test where score = 0;
```

Explain With BTree Indexes

```sql
drop index if exists test_score_zero;
create index test_score_zero on test using btree (id) where score = 0;
explain select id from test where score = 0;
```

The Hash Indexes result is

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..13578.03 rows=9867 width=4)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..11591.33 rows=4111 width=4)
        Filter: (score = 0)
```

The BTree Indexes result is

```
Index Only Scan using test_score_zero on test  (cost=0.29..262.58 rows=9867 width=4)
```

PostgreSQL Version:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) hash indexes simply do not support "Index Only Scan"

> To solve this performance problem, PostgreSQL supports index-only scans [...]
>
> The index type must support index-only scans. B-tree indexes always do. GiST and SP-GiST indexes support index-only scans for some operator classes but not others. **Other index types have no support**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

There are only very few reasons to use a hash index instead of a B-Tree index and if you expect that Index Only Scan will help performance for your queries substantially, just stick with a B-Tree index.

Comment: Hmm. But why not a normal index scan?

Comment: But if you switched to a normal index scan (by selecting "name" rather than "id"), you still get the same behavior that btree is used but hash is not.  There is something else causing the behavior, but I can't identify it.  None of the amcan* properties look relevant, but presumably one of them is.